# Ajuda, como eu salvo o caminho da imagem no meu banco?

Tags: sql

Eu queria criar um campo imagem_prod e fazer o insert, como faço?

as imagens estão nesta pasta C:/xampp/htdocs/(projeto/img/produtos)?

```
CREATE TABLE produtos (
  id int NOT NULL auto_increment primary key,
  nome varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  preco decimal(10,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB; 


INSERT INTO produtos (nome, preco) VALUES
('Presente Amor Completo', '139.99'),
('Arranjo Luz e Amor', '89.99'),
('Buquê 12 Rosas Vermelhas', '119.99'),
('Arranjo Nobre de Orquideas Lilases', '150.00');
```

Comment: Uma cadeia de caracteres contendo o texto completo do caminho até a imagem?

Comment: Poderia mostrar como fica a estrutura com um campo assim?

Comment: caminho varchar(1024).

Comment: e como fica no insert?

Comment: É um texto como qualquer outro texto.

Comment: poderia escrever, por gentileza? eu não sei como fica a estrutura do insert de um campo assim.

Comment: INSERT INTO produtos (nome, preco, imagem) VALUES
('Presente Amor Completo', 139.99, 'C:/xampp/htdocs/projeto/img/produtos/prodx.jpg'); ou algo parecido.

Comment: obrigada, vou testar.

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia fazer da seguinte maneira;

```
CREATE TABLE produtos (
  id int NOT NULL auto_increment primary key,
  nome varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  preco decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  url_imagem TEXT
) ENGINE=InnoDB; 


INSERT INTO produtos (nome, preco, url_imagem ) VALUES
('Presente Amor Completo', '139.99','C:/xampp/htdocs/projeto/img/produtos/presente.jpg'),
('Arranjo Luz e Amor', '89.99','C:/xampp/htdocs/projeto/img/produtos/arranjo.jpg'),
('Buquê 12 Rosas Vermelhas', '119.99','C:/xampp/htdocs/projeto/img/produtos/buque.jpg'),
('Arranjo Nobre de Orquideas Lilases', '150.00','C:/xampp/htdocs/projeto/img/produtos/orquideas.jpg');
```

Utilizei o Campo *url_imagem* do tipo `TEXT` para que esta coluna possa receber um número maior de caracteres, caso o caminho do arquivo seja muito grande.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Mas quando exibo por php na tela aparece apenas como texto, o que estou errando?

Comment: Você tem o caminho no banco, quando resgatar este valor você tem que coloca-lo em uma tag `<img>`. Um exemplo "<img src='".$dados['url_imagem']."' />"; desta maneira você irá passar o caminho para um elemento de imagem.

Comment: vou testar desta forma

Comment: <?php   "<img src='".$product['caminho']."' />"  ?> --- coloquei assim, mais ainda não aparece a imagem do banco

Comment: Vamos lá. Primeiro qual o método que você está fazendo para recuperar os dados do banco? você está utilizando php pelo que vi. Me mostre o loop que você está fazendo para exibir os produtos. Só para confirmar, quando você acessa os caminhos das imagens pelo navegador elas são exibidas?